# How to access a cell in LibreOffice Calc using numeric indices?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Is there a function in LibreOffice Calc that accepts an **integer x** and an **integer y** and spits out the contents of the cell with that position?

There is a function `ADDRESS` that spits out the address of a given [x;y]. The problem is that I do not know how to **dereference it.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is working for me:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5;2))
```

Where 5 is the row and 2 is the column, INDIRECT seems to resolve that reference to the actual value.

Also tested NeoOffice on OSX where this works too.

Comment: Great! Thank you! But I thought it would be simpler. It seems like an ubiquitous function.